# Which question should I denote as the origin of tikzmark?

Tags: discussion, tex-sx-package

Having finally gotten round to uploading the dread [`tikzmark` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark), I now approach the next task which is linking to the original question here and putting the "This question led to a new package" banner on it.

Only I'm not sure which to designate as the true origin.

Candidates are:

1. [How can I get an underbrace and an overbrace to partially overlap in an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297/86) The actual first appearance.  However, its use is a bit overkill for the question and it can't really be said that the *question* led to the package.
2. [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1559/86) This is the one where others started noticing it and is the one that many link back to when referring to it.  But still, the tikzmark itself is not about putting brackets next to text.
3. [tikzmark to have different behaviour if first run (and mark locations not yet available)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50015/86) This led to a major revision, including the introduction of special coordinates.  Moreover, the question was actually about the tikzmark.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does there have to be a single "origin" to the package?  If so, I would say choose the first appearance. If not, mark all three.

Comment: Thanks for your work and contribution :). Although i agree with @MatthewLeingang comment. you might be the best judge as a package author and veteran TeX.SX member.

Comment: I vote for 3 since it presumably spurred you on to package construction.  I'm not a big fan of indirect causation. :)

Comment: I'd also vote for option 3 which contains the core of the "improved" tikzmark version (even if I'm still asking myself: where has the library/extra highlighting gone?).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I took out the highlighting in order to have something reasonable to submit to CTAN.  There's lots about the highlighting that I'm unhappy with, but I didn't want it to hold up submitting the rest of the tikzmark package.